# Using ENV vars while running command using subprocess in python 3?

Tags: python, subprocess

What I am trying to achieve is - to run and return output of some automation scripts, but I am failing to understand why I can't use ENV vars in my scripts?

A simple example I am struggling to implement

```
import os
import subprocess as sp

cmd = [ 'echo', '$_TEST' ]
myenv = {**{'_TEST':"is it working?"}, **os.environ }
pipe  = sp.Popen( cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, env=myenv  );
print( pipe.communicate() )
```

What I am doing wrong?

Update: after getting correct answer.

```
import os
import subprocess as sp

cmd = [ '/bin/echo', '$_TEST' ]
myenv = {**{'_TEST':"is it working?"}, **os.environ }
pipe  = sp.Popen( " ".join(cmd), stdout=sp.PIPE, shell=True, stderr=sp.PIPE, env=myenv  );
print( pipe.communicate()  )
```

1. Need to provide a shell argument `shell=True` (or provide a path to other shell), shell we need to evaluate our variables.
2. `list` of commands should be replaced by `string` (e.g. '/bin/echo $_TEST')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitution of environment variables is performed by shell, so your solution just prints original text. The proper way to solve this task:

```
import os
import subprocess as sp

cmd = 'echo $_TEST'
myenv = {**{'_TEST':"is it working?"}, **os.environ }
pipe  = sp.Popen( cmd, shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, env=myenv  );
print( pipe.communicate() )
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I was a bit confused when I  set `shell=True` it didn't provide any output at all, but when I changed `list` to `string` as the first argument, it starts working immediately. Guess I need to read more about subprocess internals and how it works.

Comment: @OlegButuzov Yeah, it's a little bit confusing that you have to change cmd type.